# What does max_retries and retry_backoff_max mean if retry_backoff is set to True in Celery?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

The [celery documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions) gives the following example for automatically retrying a task:

```
class BaseTaskWithRetry(Task):
    autoretry_for = (TypeError,)
    retry_kwargs = {'max_retries': 5}
    retry_backoff = True
    retry_backoff_max = 700
    retry_jitter = False
```

`retry_backoff` means that Celery will use exponential backoff - so in this case (according to the docs):

> The first retry will have a delay of 1 second, the second retry will have a delay of 2 seconds, the third will delay 4 seconds, the fourth will delay 8 seconds, and so on.

However, in the example `max_retries` is five, and yet `retry_backoff_max` is 700.

I would think that if `max_retries` is set to five, then the retries would happen at one second, two seconds, four seconds, eight seconds, and sixteen seconds. That is all, because that's five retries. The backoff never gets anywhere close to 700 seconds.

Is `retry_backoff_max` in the given example pointless? What does `max_retries` of five actually mean in this example?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in this specific example, setting `retry_backoff_max` is really superfluous. However, in general case, the task can initiate retry also using `self.retry` alongside using autoretry. If you look at how the `countdown` for task retry is [calculated](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c3e041050ae252be79d9b4ae400ec0c5b2831d14/celery/app/autoretry.py#L43) you'll see that it uses the actual retries count from the task (`task.request.retries`) instead of `max_retries` attribute. `retry_backoff_max` then represents the hard limit which accounts for both types of retry.